# Function failing to return same format for every element for an atomic vector in R

Tags: r, date, vector, format

I am trying to set an unique format for every element in an atomic vector composed by dates.

Here's the code I am using:

```
dates <- c("26-08-2019", "02-09-2015", "2020-08-17", "24-07-1990",
           "2020-07-11")

dates <- as.Date(dates, format = "%Y-%m-%d")
dates
```

Console output:

```
"0026-08-20" "0002-09-20" "2020-08-17" "0024-07-19" "2020-07-11"
```

Expected output:

```
"2019-08-26" "2015-09-02" "2020-08-17" "1990-07-24" "2020-07-01"
```

Is there any other way to set an unique date format?

Comment: You could try the `anytime` package, I think it's goal is to parse dates and times in inconsistent formats. [See the package page here](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/anytime.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lubridate::parse_date_time`

```
> lubridate::parse_date_time(c("26-08-2019", "02-09-2015", "2020-08-17", "24-07-1990",
+                              "2020-07-11"), c("%d-%m-%Y", "%Y-%m-%d"))
[1] "2019-08-26 UTC" "2015-09-02 UTC" "2020-08-17 UTC" "1990-07-24 UTC" "2020-07-11 UTC"
```

Comment: It worked I just had to use ```gsub``` package to remove ```"UTC"``` character,  and then passing this vector into ```as.Date``` function